# how to apply <> operator condition in spring Repository

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa

i have SQL query i need to convert it for spring Repository the query is

```
Select * From user order where order date>start date&order date<end date;
```

Comment: This is not even a valid SQL. Please edit the question and provide more details about your DB Table and your entity.

Comment: table name is useroder and entity is values in useroder like name ,shopname,details for any order ,how we can write spring data jpa repository for above condition

Comment: Edit your question. If you want our help then show at least some minimum effort.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more info, it's hard to say for sure, but I imagine you're looking for something like this: 
findByDateBetween(...)

This is using the *Between* semantics documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

Hope that helps.